# NestJS return original response from External API

Tags: controller, nestjs, response

I have backend app based on NestJS, where I use external package/librabry.

I send a request from frontend app to backend app, the controller receive the request, call the appropriate service. The service call a method from package/library and receive response and hand it over to controller.

The response from package/library has body, header, status etc. (normally REST API response). I would like to take the original response from library/package and send it from backend controller to frontend (not only body/data, but also the headers etc.). It is there any way how to do that? Thank you!

I already tried to set manually body of response and headers in controller, but the NestJS creates  everytime *Content-Length* header, but I need to use *Transfer-encoding: chunked* header and these two headers can't be combined, what can be also problem.

Comment: You could stream the response back if it comes in as a stream/buffer object. Otherwise, if those headers are already set, I believe Nest ignores re-setting them, might be an express thing overwriting them, I'd have to check the code though to be certain. Can you provide code examples of what you're doing so we can see if anything isn't quite right? End of the day, worst comes to worst, if you use `res.send()` yourself, Nest will be completely hands off on the response headers and values